# Jagged lines while handling UV values out of range [0,1]

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I am parsing an OBJ which has texture coordinates more than 1 and less than 0 as well. I then write it back by making the UV values in the range [0,1]. Based on the understanding from [another question on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465212/mapping-wavefront-obj-texture-vertex-on-opengl) SO, am doing the conversion to the range [0,1] as follows.

```
                if (oldU > 1.0) or (oldU < 0.0):
                    oldU = math.modf(oldU)[0] # Returns the floating part
                    if oldU < 0.0 :
                        oldU = 1 + oldU

                if (oldV > 1.0) or (oldV < 0.0):
                    oldV = math.modf(oldV)[0] # Returns the floating part
                    if oldV < 0.0:
                        oldV = 1 + oldV
```

But I see some jagged lines in my output obj file and the original obj file when rendered in some software:

[image]
Original

[image]
Restricted to [0,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work not as you've expected.

Given some triangle edge that starts at `U=0.9` and ends at `U=1.1` then after your UV clipping you'll get start at `0.9` but end at `0.1` so the triangle will use different part of your texture. I believe this happens at the bottom of your mesh.

In general there's no problem with using UV outside of 0-1 range so first try to render the mesh as it is and see if you have any problems.

If you really want to move UVs to 0-1 range then scale and move UVs instead of clipping them per vertex. Iterate over all vertices and store min and max values for U and V, then scale UV for every vartex, so min becomes 0 and max becomes 1.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the problem, but I still do not understand how scaling the values will resolve this issue ? If a triangle edge is the way you describe it, I can never represent it by giving it values between 0 and 1. Instead I should probably further break down triangles with such edges in a way that all the new generated triangles have all their vertices on one side of the boundary. Then probably scaling will be of help. Could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Actually I am stitching my textures to form an atlas. So I can't be enabling GL_REPEAT later on. What I want is for all the individual textures to have their UVs restricted to [0,1] and stitch them together so that repetition is not required.

Comment: Something related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662107/how-to-use-gl-repeat-to-repeat-only-a-selection-of-a-texture-atlas-opengl

Comment: Breaking down triangles as you've said you'd need to create one of the new vertices at exactly U=1 point, so no edge crosses 1.0 value, then the next edge would start from U=0, but I see no reason for doing that. And the answer for the related question you've posted says to not to clip UVs, just to enable texture wrapping.

Comment: I understand you want to use atlas for this, you can still do it, but I don't get your mesh UVs. Could you post some screen from UV mapping of this object? Or at least show us the full texture and full rendered object?